# OpenCSV doesn't write first row of database to CSV file

Tags: java, opencsv

I created program in Java using Netbeans which downloads data from database which is then saved to CSV file using OpenCSV. However for some reason first row of database is skipped.

```
while (rs.next()){

CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\test2.csv"), ',');          
writer.writeAll(rs,false);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
}
```

Actual db data:

```
1 Mark BMW
2 John Audi
3 Nick Fiat
```

Data written to CSV file:

```
2 John Audi
3 Nick Fiat
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the call to `rs.next()` is advancing one row in your result set, and then the call to writeAll writes everything after that advancement.  try taking out the `while(rs.next)` loop block around your code and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

You should check the documentation again. it clearly shows that you dont need the while loop. You simply throw the resultset at it and define if the headers should be return or not.

```
writer.writeAll(yourResultSet, true);
```

In the above case, the headers will be included to the generated csv file

Comment: Just incase you are still following this up. writer.writeAll(resultset, true) will work, however, for larger resultsets, its very slow.